# Trying to extrude bottom wall layout to build a house?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I can't get the entire base of the walls to extrude upwards in order to finish modeling this house. Additionally, the areas that are already extruded are areas that I did not wish to be extruded and I can't figure out how to reverse it.

*House Layout:*

[image]
[image]

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Did you try *W > Remove Doubles* before extruding? It looks like you have extraneous faces at your edges.

Comment: Yes, it said there were 0 doubles. That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend to [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and paste the link into your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I'm still new to this site.

Comment: Instead of extruding, use bridge edge loops to connect the parts you want.

Comment: Go to the link I provided, click where it says "Drag a file here to upload a .blend or click to browse," select your .blend file, click open, go back to this question, copy the url, paste it in on the Blend Exchange page where it says "Enter the url of the question on blender.stackexchange,"click the big blue "Upload" button, copy the provided, shaking link into your question by clicking the edit button, pasting it, and clicking "Save Edits."

Comment: Blend File uploaded

Comment: @DustinSexson Working on an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, first things first. Let's identify your problems, which I did after a couple minutes.

### Problems

- You can *Remove Doubles* to remove 4,332 vertices.
- Your bottom area has a tiny amount of thickness, which is preventing *Extrude* from working correctly.
- *Normals* are all over the place.
- Some faces are missing.

### Solution

Beginning from your uploaded .blend file.

1. Begin by keying <kbd>A</kbd> twice to select everything and key <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
2. Enter *Front Orthographic View* by keying <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>. This will allow us to remove the top and few walls that extruded correctly.
3. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> to enter *Face Mesh Select Mode* and <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter *Wireframe View*. Key <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything. Face select mode allows us to select the correctly extruded middle faces. Wireframe allows us to select vertices that are obscured by other parts of the mesh, rather than just the faces we can see.
4. Use *<kbd>B</kbd>ox Select* to select these faces:
    [image]
5. Key <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Faces* to delete these faces. If you zoom in very close on the bottom, you can see its thickness:
    [image]
6. Key <kbd>Z</kbd> to exit *Wireframe View* and return to *Solid View*. Key <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to enter *Top View*.
7. *Box Select* the entire grid. Because you are in *Orthographic Solid View*, only the top faces will be selected.
8. Key <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Vertices* to delete all top vertices. This will remove the mesh interference.
9. However, if you try to extrude now, you may get weird glitches. You must select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Normals*.
10. You may want to <kbd>F</kbd>ill in some faces now.
     [image]
11. You can now use <kbd>E</kbd> to *Extrude* up on the *Z-Axis*.
12. Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> one last time and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> once again to finish touching up *Normals*.

*Finished Product:*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have tons of duplicated vertices.

In edit mode select all and press remove doubles.

[image]

Then delete the top part of the model.

Then on the bottom part you can see that the mesh has already been extruded. So I'm going to presume that the top layer you can do without. In top solid view select the top faces and delete them.

[image]

Now you can extrude.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've got yourself into a sticky situation here. First off, you may want to remove doubles by hitting "W" in edit mode then selecting "Remove Doubles". You can alternatively find this setting in the toolshelf (toggle by pressing "T"). Second, some of your normals are facing the wrong way, which can affect extruding. Recalculate them by selecting all in Edit Mode then by pressing "Ctrl + N". Third, you've already extruded the layout, so selecting all then extruding won't work. Select only the top faces by going to the top view (NUMPAD 7) and Orthographic mode (NUMPAD 5) then box selecting by pressing "B" then clicking and dragging to make a box over the entire layout.

[image]

You can exit Orthographic Mode (NUMPAD 5) and top view at this point. Now, since the model is already extruded, you can just move the top layer along the Z axis by pressing the blue arrow or by pressing "G" then "Z". However, you can still extrude it if you'd like, it would just create more polygons, thus extending render times a bit.

[image]

Hoped this solved your problem. Happy blendering :D

Answer (score -2):

From personal experience, I suggest you switch to edge select mode. That should do the trick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! How do I deselect ignored to actually extrude the faces making a physical 3-D object? When I hit (E) it seems to actually Duplicate the object.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If I select on individual section of the mesh and extrude it creates a proper extrusion, but extruding all seems to only extrude a few places and duplicate the rest. Like in the original photo.

Comment: Even in edge select mode?

Comment: Can you send me the .blend file?

Comment: I'm still learning all this and I have no idea how to send it to you.

Comment: Ok, no problem! Can you post a screenshot of what happens if you use edge select mode?

Comment: I am glad you figured it out! Please @ mention me if you have any more questions